# Compare two datasets and get which row is different

Tags: c#, linq, loops, dataset, compare

I have got two dataset:
1.-

```
<dataset1>
  <articles>
    <name>name1</name>
    <id>R12</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name2</name>
    <id>R13</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name3</name>
    <id>R14</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name4</name>
    <id>R15</id>
  </articles>
    <articles>
    <name>name5</name>
    <id>R16</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name6</name>
    <id>R17</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name7</name>
    <id>R18</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name8</name>
    <id>R19</id>
  </articles>
</dataset>
```

2.

```
<dataset2>
  <articles>
    <name>name1</name>
    <id>R12</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name2</name>
    <id>R13</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>nameTT</name>
    <id>R14</id>
  </articles>
  <articles>
    <name>name3</name>
    <id>R20</id>
  </articles>
</dataset>
```

The first dataset is the main dataset, the second one is from the user. I want to compare and know if the data in the second exists in the first one. 
So, in this case, the data of the second dataset, the first 2 rows are ok, but the last 2 rows are not ok because these rows are not in the first one.
I have tried looping 2 dataset like this:

```
 foreach (DataRow data1 in dataset1.Tables[0].Rows)//
                {
                    foreach (DataRow data2 in data2.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (!(data1["id"] == data2["id"] && data1["name"] == data2["name"]))
                        {
                            return "error";
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But it is not working because the row colud be later tahn this comparison. I would like to tell the user: Sorry but the data:nameTT with the id:RT14 is not valid data and exit
Any ideas? THanks!

Comment: Why are you comparing every row with every row? I think you should just compare pairs

Comment: A hint; instead of immediately returning an error, you should return when there `is` a match. You can return an error if you get to the end and there is no match.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare pairs.
And I want to now which pair is not the correct one. When I get one pair that is not correct, I return error and finish

Comment: Can you access row like this?:
dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[0]

Comment: Do you still have a problem? Any of this posts helped you? If you resolve your problem by yourself, please post your answer :)

Comment: I'd like to test all the answer to take the better one.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that both data sets have the same count of rows. You can check if count differs by yourself.

```
for (int i=0; i < dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count(); i++)
{
    if (!(dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"] == dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"] 
          && dataset1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"] == dataset2.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"]))
     {
         return i;
     }
}
```

I'm returning here the index of row which is not matching. You can return negative number to indicate that all rows are matching.

It only works when both datasets have the same length. You can iterate to minimal length of both sets like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < Math.Min(dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count(),dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count()); i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about LINQ?

```
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("articles");
            dataTable.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);

            string xmlData = "<XmlDS><articles><name>name1</name><id>R12</id></articles><articles><name>name2</name><id>R13</id></articles><articles><name>name3</name><id>R14</id></articles><articles><name>name4</name><id>R15</id></articles><articles><name>name5</name><id>R16</id></articles><articles><name>name6</name><id>R17</id></articles><articles><name>name7</name><id>R18</id></articles><articles><name>name8</name><id>R19</id></articles></XmlDS>";

            System.IO.StringReader xmlSR = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData);

            dataSet.ReadXml(xmlSR, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);

            DataSet dataSet2 = new DataSet();
            DataTable dataTable2 = new DataTable("articles");
            dataTable2.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dataTable2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dataSet2.Tables.Add(dataTable2);

            string xmlData2 = "<XmlDS><articles><name>name1</name><id>R12</id></articles><articles><name>name2</name><id>R13</id></articles><articles><name>nameTT</name><id>R14</id></articles><articles><name>name3</name><id>R20</id></articles></XmlDS>";
            System.IO.StringReader xmlSR2 = new System.IO.StringReader(xmlData2);

            dataSet2.ReadXml(xmlSR2, XmlReadMode.IgnoreSchema);

            var d1 = dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
            var d2 = dataSet2.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
            var result = d1.Where(a => d2.All(dt => (string)dt["id"] != (string)a["id"] || (string)dt["name"] != (string)a["name"])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Linq to XML in this cases like this. Hmm Note there are probably places I should check for null but I haven't

```
var dataSet1 = Your First XML DataSet   
var dataSet2 = Your Second XML DataSet

XElement dataSet1Tree = XElement.Parse(dataSet1);
var dataSet1List = from el in dataSet1Tree.Elements("articles")
                select new 
                            {
                                Name = el.Elements("name").First().Value,
                                ID = el.Elements("id").First().Value
                            };
XElement dataSet2Tree = XElement.Parse(dataSet2);
var dataSet2List = from el in dataSet2Tree.Elements("articles")
                select new 
                            {
                                Name = el.Elements("name").First().Value,
                                ID = el.Elements("id").First().Value
                            };

foreach(var set2 in dataSet2List)
{
    if (dataSet1List.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == set2.Name && x.ID == set2.ID) == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid article : "+set2.ID+" "+set2.Name);
}


}
```